# HTML: BOTON - Para compartir una imagen jpg en historias de instagram

Tags: html

HAGO UNA CONSULTA:
Si yo quiero poner un botón en mi sitio web que es de lanzamiento de un producto por ej: UNA LANDING PAGE QUE HAGA REFERENCIA A UN PRODUCTO QUE LANZAMOS.

Y DEBAJO PONGO UN BOTON PARA QUE LA GENTE QUE LA VISITA PUEDA COMPARTIR EL LANZAMIENTO EN HISTORIAS DE INSTAGRAM:

AL BOTON LE QUIERO INTEGRAR UN JPG DE 1920X1080, que al tocar el botón te abra la app de Instagram con la historia del jpg ya cargado, como cuando pones para subir una historia desde la app misma de instagram.

DEBO USAR UN INTENT IMPLICIT? O QUE ME RECOMIENDAN QUE SERÍA LO MEJOR?

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] para que sepas como funciona el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla!. También sería bueno que le eches un vistazo a [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Botones de redes sociales para Instagram**

Instagram no ofrece botones Compartir o Me gusta, lo cual tiene sentido, ya que la naturaleza de Instagram como una plataforma móvil para compartir fotos y videos significa que no es realmente adecuado para gustar y compartir contenido web.

En cambio, Instagram solía ofrecer insignias que podía usar para enviar personas desde su sitio web directamente a su feed de Instagram, pero esas insignias ya no están disponibles. Los cambios en la API de Instagram también han dificultado que los proveedores externos creen botones e insignias funcionales de Instagram.

Eso significa que te quedan muy pocas opciones en términos de botones para compartir en redes sociales para Instagram.

Comment: consulta, instagram://story-camera me lleva a como si yo desde mi app de instagram pusiera para subir una historia, hay manera de que a este enlace le sume tmb la imagen que quiero que compartan en su historia?